# Build only updates Simulator binaries, not iPhone ones

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios-simulator

I have some code that runs fine - all lines are executed as expected - on the iOS Simulator.  But when I switch to the iPhone, some of the code isn't even run! [Xcode 4.4.1] For example, here are two lines, the first was in the original source, of a a few days ago, the second just added today:

NSLog(@"Original text");

NSLog(@"Newly added text");

The second line, added more recently, simply does not show in the debug output when the App runs on the iPhone, but it's there when it runs on the Simulator.

It looks like none of the changes I make get to the new version gets linked into the iPhone build.    It's as if the the object file that gets linked for the iPhone version is simply NOT update during a build, even though the source changed.  I've done a Product->Clean, but it did not help...

I'd be grateful for any help/suggestions, as I am quite perplexed.

Comment: Try deleting the app from the iPhone. Have you changed the bundle identifier recently?

Comment: yes... Bundle ID was changed when App got submitted.  [Beginner's mistake - I put down a bundle ID during the submission process without carefully checking it in Xcode (where it was different).  So I had to change it in Xcode to make it match what I put on the submission form.  Learned my lesson, but how does this affect linking?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to debug code, which was compiled in release mode. So lots of info is optimized out. Set Debug in your scheme configuration.

Comment: As near as I can tell, the scheme is displaying Debug for both the iPhone and the Simulator.  [This is for Product->Edit Scheme, and then looking at Build Configuration.  Is there something else I need to examine?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the line where you have written the NSLog statement.It will tell you whats exactly happening.

Comment: I do add a breakpoint to the "new" NSLog line, but the debugger only breaks a few lines below it, in the original code.  It's as if the debugger doesn't even see the breakpoint (where I put it), and only breaks a couple lines below.

Comment: Eventually Xcode crashed (for some unknown, probably unrelated reason).  When I relaunched it, the linking "problem" seems to have resolved itself.  I now see my edits both in the Simulator and the iPhone.  So, it would seem the problem is solved.  But I hate it when I don't know why it occurred, or how a crash and restart fixed it.... But I am grateful that this happened anyway!